# How to display the task which I have completed in my code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
let todos = [
    {
        id: 1,
        task: 'Attend conference',
        isCompleted: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        task: "Upload JavaScript tutorial",
        isCompleted: false
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        task: 'Study',
        isCompleted: true
    }
];

for(let i = 0; i < todos.length; i++){
    console.log(todos[i].isCompleted)
};
```

I am trying to output the tasks that I have completed (isCompleted: true). The output should be something like:

```
Attend conference
Study
```

However, my output is:

```
true

false

true
```

Comment: Instead of printing the attribute `isCompleted` check it, and if it's `true` print `todos[i].task`

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green checkmark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should write an `if` condition in the `for` block scope like this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < todos.length; i++){
 if(todos[i].isCompleted)
    console.log(todos[i].task)
};
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For filtering:

```
console.log(todos.filter((item) => item.isCompleted))
```

For show names:

```
todos.filter((item) => item.isCompleted).map((item) => item.task).forEach(console.log)
```

Comment: 1. After filtering you should `map` it to task (name). 2. The OP wants the output in separate lines so this won't work

Comment: console.log(todos.filter((item) => item.isCompleted).map((item) => item.task))

Comment: `todos.filter((item) => item.isCompleted).map((item) => item.task).forEach(console.log)`